# Can a noun be supported by 2 prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

See this sentence:

> Partner A will have a contract with our company with following missions:...

It can be written into two separate sentences:

> - Partner A will have a contract with our company.
> - The contract has the following missions:...

If I write

> A contract with our company with following missions

like as in the first sentence, then would it cause a certain ambiguity or not?

Comment: Kati, you might be interested in our [sister site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), ELL, which is a good site for basic English questions. Please  have a look at the quick tour of [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to determine where you can best be helped!

Comment: There are times when a noun can be preceded by two prepositions, such as *in* and *to* (which has become *into*) or *from behind* (the noise came from behind the wall). The two prepositions in your example (both *with*) each have their own noun (company and missions, respectively.) But your sentence starts with two articles (*A* and *an*). That is not grammatical. Also, *missions* should have an article before it.

Comment: a partner name "A"

Comment: That is usually referred to as *Partner A*.

Comment: There's nothing incorrect or unusual about "A contract with our company with **the** following missions" as far as prepositions are concerned.

Comment: As for "can a noun be supported by 2 prepositions," why would you think not?

Comment: does that make the sentence ambiguos? for example, it could be "the missions of the company", not "the missions stated in the contract"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better wording would be:

> ... a contract with our company that has the following missions: ...

This eliminates the ambiguity about which noun *with* attaches to. Unless it's clear from context, when you have a string of prepositional phrases, each attaches to the noun immediately before it. For example, in

> the house on the end of the street next to the river,

the street is next to the river, and not the house. You can fix this by inserting an *and*:

> the house on the end of the street **and** next to the river.

So you could also fix the OP's sentence as follows:

> a contract with our company and with the following missions: ...

but I don't like that as much in this case because the two *with*'s are used in different senses.

Comment: sool solution, thax u very much